# Mental Telepathy

Tags: sources-mekorot, psych-mentalhealth

In Rabbi Immanuel Schochet's introduction to the fundamentals to proving religion. He mentions mental telepathy as a phenomenon that although uncommon does exist.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tY5Qzo0Kdfo -In the early section he makes that claim.I am tired and having a hard time finding the quote exactly.

Assuming Rabbi Immanuel Schochet is correct, could anyone provide me a source for this?? I would prefer a rishon or achron and not from kabbalistic literature if possible.

Comment: Well according to this Medrash Rabbah (65:12 parshas toldos) knowing someone's thoughts are hidden from others.תני שבעה דברים מכוסים מבני אדם, ואלו הן: יום המיתה, ויום הנחמה, ועומק הדין, ואין אדם יודע במה הוא משתכר, ואין אדם יודע מה בלבו של חבירו, ואין אדם יודע מה בעיבורה של אשה, ומלכות הרשעה אימתי נופלת.

Comment: Does this Medrash conflict with the concept of mental telepathy as a means of communicating one's ideas telepathically? I am looking for a source for that.

Comment: It should be noted that the intellectual generally scoffs at such claims, and indeed various skeptic societies offer large sums of money to anyone who can perform such a feat in a controlled setting. No one has collected see e.g. [here]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Million_Dollar_Paranormal_Challenge

Comment: I'm sure much to the consternation of many a modern, self-described Maimonidean rationalist, I believe there's actually a Moreh Nevuchim to the effect, though I don't remember the exact perek... ( @WFB ?)

Comment: I believe @Loewian is referring to the Rambam's comments in his introduction to Perush ha-Mishnah

Comment: See also http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3305206/Five-year-old-savant-LA-displays-signs-telepathic-learning-seven-languages-studied-scientists-mother-filmed-reciting-numbers-written-secret.html @Loewian

Comment: See Rav Shilat's commentary to Hakdamah le-Perush ha-Mishnah, piska bet and Moreh Nevukhim 2:37, 38 which he references.

Comment: @wfb The Hakdamah to Pirush Hamishna mentions clairvoyance rather than telepathy per se.

Comment: @sam It's also in Pesachim

Answer (score 2):

in the chovos halevavos [gate 8](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=391) some hints to this

> And he will be on an exalted level, among the levels of the Chasidim
>   (extremely pious), and a high level among the Tzadikim (righteous),
>   and he will be able to see without his physical eyes, and hear without
>   his physical ears, and speak without a tongue

Marpe Lenefesh commentary there: he will be able to speak to others without a physical tongue

then later

> And when you do this with a faithful heart and a pure soul, your mind
>   will become illuminated, and you will see the path to all of the
>   exalted qualities, and the yetzer (evil inclination) will not have a
>   way to reach you and entice you, and you will reach the status of one
>   treasured by G-d. A new, strange, supernal sense will arouse in you,
>   unfamiliar to you of all the senses you are used to knowing, as the
>   wise man said: "A man's wisdom makes his face to shine, and the
>   boldness of his face is changed" (Koheles 8:1)

Answer (score 2):

The [Gemara in Sota 38b](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%97_%D7%91) says that birds recognize when the bait for them is put out with a stingy heart, and they won't come.

The [Gemara Bava Basra 16b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%98%D7%96_%D7%91) describes Iyov's friends as being aware of each other's pain, although they were far from each other, through a crown or tree that they all had and that would wither if one was in trouble.

The Maharal explains that this is describing how they were completely united. This suggests that it was some form of telepathy that they were tuned in to each other enough to be able to sense remotely when something was wrong. People in our times have had such experiences, but not reliably.

Then we have the [famous Pasuk in Mishlei](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%96_%D7%99%D7%98)(see Ralbag) telling us that the way you feel about a friend he will feel about you.

There is also the [Gemara in Sanhedrin](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A6%D7%94_%D7%90) About Yoav finding out about king David being in trouble.

These aren't conclusive but are easier understood with the concept of some form of telepathy. This won't prove anything to someone who didn't already believe in it but can serve as confirmation.

Comment: 1. See the Maharsha there, not through "clairvoyance"

Comment: The Maharal in Chidushei Hagados explains it as a vibe that they get. This actually answers the Maharsha's question better than his own second approach, which seems to attribute logical reasoning to the birds.