# Is Telepathy Kishuf?

Tags: sorcery-magic-kishuf

There is something called Telepathy. Telepathy is defined as "the supposed communication of thoughts or ideas by means other than the known senses." I have seen some videos say that it means that when you listen to this music, think about a person, you can make them feel something for you (This is just what the video said and is the best example, that is why I am giving it) or manipulate them to do something. I have seen other places claiming you could use it to talk to the dead. I am not saying it actually works. I am just asking out of interest if it is considered Kishuf or not?

According to this question it would seem Rabbi Immanuel Schochet would hold that you could do it: [Mental Telepathy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53505/mental-telepathy)

Comment: To the best of my understanding, kishuf means using forbidden supernatural means to manipulate nature. If telepathy is natural, it would not be kishuf. That is assuming it actually exists.

Comment: @N.T. Thank you for your comment. But I have a question. What would be considered kishuf then? (If you could provide an example that would be great).